# defineObjects giving ClassNotFound in LR 6.0.5

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I am trying to migrate liferay from 5.3.2 to 6.0.6. When I Place custom portlet, I am getting the exception as

com.liferay.portal.servet.taglib.portlet.DefineObjectsTagUtil , ClassNotFoundException.

I followed the steps in this [Link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6936575)

But when I cross check the existence of util-taglib.jar, it is already in ROOT/WEB-INF/lib. They also told to add the taglibs,

```
1<taglib>
2    <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet</taglib-uri>
3    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld</taglib-location>
4</taglib>
5<taglib>
6    <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
7    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld</taglib-location>
8</taglib>
```

In this, line 5 to 8 already exists in web.xml file. Added 1 to 4 lines and restarted the tomcat.

Still the tomcat complains the ClassNotFound exception mentioned above. Can any one help me to solve the issue please?

Comment: yes, restarted the liferay tomcat.

Comment: @codeMan I solved this, posted the answer. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed once I am replacing the util-taglib.jar from ROOT/WEB-INF/lib to custom portlet library solves the issue.

Thank you.